# Is the `after_script` always executed, even for cancelled jobs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script) isn't clear on whether the `after_script` is executed for cancelled jobs:

> `after_script` is used to define the command that will be run after for all jobs, including failed ones.

I'm doing potentially critical cleanup in the `after_script` and while cancelled jobs should be rare, I'd like to know that my clean up is guaranteed to happen.

Answer (score 3):

## No, I ran some tests and here are the behaviours I exhibited:

```
after_script:
  - echo "This is not executed when a job is cancelled."
  - echo "A failing command, like this one, doesn't fail the job." && false
  - echo "This is not executed because the previous command failed."
```

### 1. `after_script` is not executed when a job is cancelled

There's an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2486) for this on gitlab.com, so if this is affecting you, head over there and make some noise.

### 2. If a command in the `after_script` fails, the rest aren't executed

This is quite easy to work around:

```
after_script:
  - potentially failing command || true
  - next command
```

Replace `potentially failing command` with your command and the `next command` will execute regardless of whether `potentially failing command` passed or failed.

One could argue that this behaviour is actually desired, as it gives some flexibility to the user, but it might be counterintuitive to some.